# XPATH: selecting text node with an embedded node

Tags: xml, xpath

having the following XML code:

```
<div class="content">
<ul>
<li>
<b>Item model number:</b>
   FCC5302Q-2
</li>
</ul>
```

I used this xpath expression to select the li node text:

```
//*[contains(@class, "content")]//li[b/text()="item model number"]/text()
```

And for some reason it fails to pick the text of the li element.
Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use single quotes
2. Match cases
3. Watch out for the brackets you use..

Try this XPath..

```
//*[contains(@class, 'content')]//li/b[text()='Item model number:']/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you write the `<b>` element text verbatim, including case.

```
//*[contains(@class, "content")]//li[b/text()="Item model number:"]/text()
```